# Visual Studio Code: setting up environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

could not find this ability, is this really there in the configuration of VSCode?
to add environment variables to specific workspace? I mean settings.json which is located in the work folder.
So I'm using cmake tools extension which requires some environment variables for the build

Answer (score 1):

I think that functionality is not yet supported in VSCode. There is a [feature-request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13965), though, and if you want it implemented you should add a thumb-up reaction to the issue's first comment, or even better, code it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime this is supported, see the `cmake.environment`, `cmake.BuildEnvironment` and `cmake.configureEnvironment` [extension settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/develop/docs/cmake-settings.md).